# how to know the which archetype an existing maven project is built on?

Tags: java, maven

I have to create a new Java project using Maven, But I have an already created project whose archetype I need to use for the new project as well. So how can I know about the archetype used in the existing project.

Thanks

Comment: i'm pretty sure you can't. You could have two archetypes with the exact same structure so from the output structure of the project you wouldn't be able to tell. There isn't any metadata stored about it either.

Comment: Check the terminal log in search of any `mvn archetype` command that could have originated the project you're working on

Answer (score 12):

You can't. You could have two archetypes with the exact same structure so from the output structure of the project you wouldn't be able to tell. There isn't any metadata stored about it either.